# Robots are supposed to make mistakes, so they're not more perfect than their creators

Tags: story-identification, comics

In the story, a robot or computer made a mistake and explained that it was implementing a policy of not being better than its creators. I think this may have been collectively agreed by all the AIs in the story.

I had thought it was part of Mark Stanley's Freefall comic, perhaps the ship's computer, but I can't locate it with a keyword search for 'error' or 'mistake' or 'perfect'.

I don't think it was a TV show or movie.

(This query is prompted by an automated process going wrong at work - I wanted to cite this story, but failed to dredge it up from my memory banks.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So you can't recall if it's a comic or a short story?

Comment: @DavidW Hi, thanks. I'm afraid not. I'm pretty sure it was text, and as I say, I thought it was Freefall's ship's computer. I notice that not all the early strips' text is transcribed though... I could make it this evening's project to shovel it through an OCR.

Comment: @TimBaverstock: The first several years are available as [ZIP files](http://freefall.purrsia.com/zipped/zipped.htm) if you don't want to have to load individual pages.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're thinking of [Robert Sheckley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley)'s 1968 novel [*Dimension of Miracles*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9687) which can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dimensionofmirac0000shec).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Miracles) plot summary:

> Thanks to a computer error, Tom Carmody, an unlucky civil servant, wins the main prize of the Galactic Lottery. Being a human from the Earth, he doesn't possess galactic status and shouldn't even be eligible. However, he obtains the Prize before the mistake is found out and is allowed to keep it. That's when his adventure begins, since, not being a space-traveling creature, he has no homing instinct that can guide him back to Earth, and so the galactic lottery organizers cannot transport him home. At the same time, his removal from his home environment has caused, by the 'universal law of predation', a predatory entity to spring into existence that perpetually pursues and aims to destroy him. So Carmody is forced to be on the run, and with the help of his Prize meets several well-meaning (but usually not very competent) aliens that attempt to find where, when and which Earth he belongs on. He ends up transporting from Earth to Earth: different phases and realities of his planet, which of course, is not in the time or condition he expects it to be.

Excerpt:

> It became painfully evident to all concerned that a tragic mistake had been made. The Messenger was recalled and accused of malfunctionism, in that he did not perceive the obvious. The Clerk stoutly maintained his innocence, however, pointing out various considerations which no one considered for a moment.
>
> Among those consulted was the Sweepstakes Computer, which had in point of fact committed the actual error. Instead of making excuses or apologies, the Computer claimed the error as his own and took evident pride in it.
>
> "I was constructed," the Computer said, "to extremely close tolerances. I was designed to perform complex and exacting operations, allowing no more than one error per five billion transactions."
>
> "So?" asked the Clerk.
>
> "The conclusion is clear," the Computer said. "**I was programmed for error, and I performed as I was programmed. You must remember, gentlemen, that for a machine, error is an ethical consideration, indeed, the only ethical consideration. A perfect machine would be an impossibility; any attempt to create a perfect machine would be a blasphemy.** All life, even the limited life of a machine, has error built into it; it is one of the few ways in which life can be differentiated from the determinism of unliving matter. Complex machines such as myself occupy an ambiguous zone between living and nonliving. Were we never to err, we would be inapropos, hideous, immoral. Malfunction, gentlemen, is, I submit, our means of rendering worship to that which is more perfect than we, but which still does not permit itself a visible perfection. So, if error were not divinely programmed into us, we would malfunction spontaneously, to show that modicum of free will which, as living creatures, we partake in."
>
> Everyone bowed their heads, for the Sweepstakes Computer was talking of holy matters. The alien Carmody brushed away a tear, and said:
>
> "I cannot disagree, although I do not concur. The right to be wrong is fundamental throughout the cosmos. This machine has acted ethically."
>
> "Thank you," the Computer said simply. "I try."
>
> "But the rest of you," the alien Carmody said, "have merely acted stupidly."
>
> "That is our unalterable privilege," the Messenger reminded him. "Stupidity in the malperformance of our functions is our own form of religious error. Humble as it is, it is not to be despised.